# how to find and access the matched cell/range using office js in excel

Tags: excel, office-js

I need to access (retrieve/modify) data on the same row or column of the cell that match the keyword.

I am able to use `.find > .load('address') > .address` to get the address of the matched cell but in the form of `"sheetName!A1"`.

How do I use this address inside of `getRange()`? Do I use regex to remove the `"sheetName!"` or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `getRange("sheetName!A1")` to get range object of sheetName A1 cell. 
No need to remove `"sheetName!"`